# Invalid regular expression in Javascript on Lookarounds

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having a problem with the regex that work in Expresso but not in the javascript code. I know that there are also two other question with the same topic, but can't figure out how to implement an alternative to my regex so that it will work also in javascript.

So my expression is:

```
((?<=\bvar)\s\w*\s?)=\s?function(\s*\([^)]*\))
```

Used in javascript like that:

```
var  functionsReg =    /((?<=\bvar)\s\w*\s?)=\s?function(\s*\([^)]*\))/gm;
var match = functionsReg.exec(func);
```

and I'm expecting to be able to get for the values for each regex group.
like:

```
var name = match[0];
var params = match[1];
```

I found out that the problem is from the `(?<=\bvar)`

But I can not find the alternative for this syntax because in the end I want to be able to access the text like in the below image.
[image]

Comment: [A must read ...](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match the `var` in a non-capture group:

```
/(?:var)\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*function(\s*\([^)]*\))/g
```